# unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type

Tags: sql, go

I want to select fild in database and return 3 vriables with golang, 
this is my actual code :

```
func db_tabela_select(cliente string) (id string, cod1 string, cod2 string, cod3 string) {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", mysql_login)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    var Saldo, grup1, grup2, grup3, timestamp, user_agent string

    err = db.QueryRow(fmt.Sprintf("select * from db_tabela WHERE `cliente`='%s' LIMIT 1;", string(cliente) )).Scan(
        &id, &cliente, &Saldo, &cod1, &cod2, &cod3, &grup1, &grup2, &grup3, &user_agent, &timestamp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("cod results : ", cod1, cod2, cod3)
    }


    return id, cod1, cod2, cod3
}
```

return me this error, and i don't understend where is my mistake:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 2: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <
nil> into type *string
```

Comment: Don't use Printf et al. for SQL queries. See [the example on DB.Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) for how to pass parameters safely.

Comment: Queryrow does not takes fmt Sprintf Should read more on [Query Row](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow)

Comment: You are trying to scan NULL into string, but strings can't be nil. Use sql.NullString instead, but only after you removed the Printf.

Answer (score 0):

Since the DB field was specifying `null` instead of `not null`, I had to replace this:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    TheDatetime time.Time `json:"the_datetime"`
}
```

by:

```golang
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

type MyStruct struct {
    TheDatetime sql.NullTime `json:"the_datetime"`
}
```